ffmpeg — маркировка кадров видео
Есть задача — два видео побить на кадры. Каждый кадр первого видео маркировать красными пикселами (3x1 pixel в левом верхнем углу кадра), а каждый кадр второго - зелеными.
Я сперва разбиваю оба видео на кадры и делаю маркировку
ffmpeg -i "С:\film\film1.mp4" -vf "drawbox=x=0:y=0:w=5:h=3:color=green:t=fill" "C:\film\a%d.png"

ffmpeg -i "C:\film\film2.mp4" -vf "drawbox=x=0:y=0:w=5:h=3:color=red:t=fill" "C:\film\b%d.png"

Затем переименовываю файлы, выстраивая их в нужной последовательности...
И склеиваю в итоговое видео:
ffmpeg -framerate 120 -i "F:\film\%d.png" -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 1 -pix_fmt yuv422p10le -c:a pcm_s16le -b:a 48000 "F:\film\output.mov"

Но проблема заключается в том, что при таком подходе влияние кодека распространяется не только на сами кадры, но и на мои метки, от чего метки размываются по краям и слегка искажаются в цвете.
Вопрос:
Можно ли как-то расставить метки уже после сборки итогового видео? Чтобы на них не влиял используемый кодек.
